# How to Convert to Decimal formated gridview cell with DataFormatString="{0:#,###,##0.00}"

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying  to Convert to Decimal formatted with `DataFormatString="{0:#,###,##0.00}"` gridview cell. The function `Convert.ToDecimal(gridview.Rows[0].Cells[1])` returns something like `"wrong string format"`.

Comment: What is your gridview value ?

Comment: which format u need Ex(dd/MM/yyyy)?

Comment: What's the value of `gridview.Rows[0].Cells[1]`?

Comment: value is 1 234 012,01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that format which you are using for decimal is not correct for Culture which is used in your application.

There are two solutions:
1. Use `DataFormatString="{0:D}"` for cell
2. Try to use `Decimal.TryParse` with correct `NumberStyles` and `FormatProvider`. Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ew0seb73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

In your case you should use fr-FR culture as follows:

> Decimal.TryParse(gridview.Rows[0].Cells[0], NumberStyles.Any,
>   CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"), out val)

Comment: the format in gridview is a request from user. i had no problem with Convert.ToDecima() using  DataFormatString="{F2}" ensted of  DataFormatString="{0:#,###,##0.00}"

Comment: by the link value = "1 345,978";
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
// Displays:
//       Unable to convert '1 345,978'.

Comment: You should use fr-FR culture for parsing:
Decimal.TryParse("1 234 012,01", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"), out dec)